# Initializing Zend 2 I18N translator to use existing gettext files

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-translate

I have gettext translation files setup something like this:

`myapp/i18n/locale/da_DK/LC_MESSAGES/generic.mo`

`myapp/i18n/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/generic.mo`

I am trying to use Zend I18n translation component within my application e.g.

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
$locale='da_DK';
$tr =new Translator();
$tr->addTranslationFile('gettext',"i18n/locale/$locale/LC_MESSAGES/generic.mo",'generic',$locale);
```

Also tried this:

```
  $tr->addTranslationFilePattern('gettext',"i18n/locale","%s.mo",'generic');
```

Is this right setting to pick `i18n/locale/da_DK/LC_MESSAGES/%s.mo` files, given locale is  `da_DK`?

I tested it by:

```
$tr->setLocale($locale);
echo $tr->translate('Search');
```

which is not working, I am not sure if this is desired configuration.

Edit:

I am not using Zend Framework as whole, instead only using some selected modules. So I need this working independently of ZF2.

As in ZF2 service manager is setup to auto initialize translator given a configuration e.g.

```
 'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_GB',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Question here is how that fits if we use ONLY translate component out of the Zend context independently for standard gettext file structure. Which is:

```
locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/
locale/en_UK/LC_MESSAGES/
locale/da_DK/LC_MESSAGES/
locale/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `.` in `module.config`

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
)
```

put `*.mo` in language folder
`Application->language->` `*.mo` and `*.po`

**Update 1:**

1. be sure path of mo file is correct.
2. in `poedit` `Catalog->properties->Sources keywords` check translate word exist and it's better that be first.

Comment: I am not using zend framework , its independent project,using only zend translate module